# In MVC how can I edit records in memory without saving to database fisrt

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a scenario in MVC where I am uploading Excel files using OPEN XML to read spreadsheets, I however do not want to save these records to the database yet, as I perform validation against the records and if validation succeeds I then save the record to the database, this is for performance reasons as I can have 1000's of records in the excel spreadsheet, I was able to edit well if I first save the records to the database, I would simply read them from db by Id , modify and then update/save the changes. I don't want to do this, I need to enable my app to read the the records in memory edit, re-validate then save only valid data, how can I do this in MVC, please see my current code below which uses the approach of saving the records first which is what I want to avoid.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {


        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        CleanSupplierClaim cleanData = await db.CleanSupplierClaims.FindAsync(id);

        if (cleanData == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(cleanData);
    }

// POST: /Claim/Edit/5
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Action,Line_Number,Total_Claim,Currency,ClaimReference,ST_Key,Warning,Error_1,Error_2,Error,Domain_Username")] CleanSupplierClaim cleanData)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (cleanData.Id == 0)
        {
            db.CleanSupplierClaims.Add(cleanData);
        }
        else
        {
            db.Entry(cleanData).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        //return PartialView();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("RedirectToValidateClaimsView");
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do I understand you right: You want to upload some Excel files, then let them in the Memory and edit them in your view? If everything is ok you want to save them in your DB?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do, I do not want to save the records to DB, as I need to validate them, if valid only then I save to db, reason is that I have 1000's of records

Answer (score 3):

HTTP is stateless.  You have to write data *somewhere*.

"Somewhere" could be:

- In page data (hidden form fields, JavaScript variables, etc.)
- In cookies (not very suitable for large amounts of data)
- In session state
- In static variables (probably not good in a web application for a couple of reasons, but an option nonetheless)
- In a file
- In a separate database (maybe a local SQL database file for just that application, or maybe a document database, etc.)
- In the main database but in separate tables (tables meant to hold "temporary" data which hasn't been committed to the "real" tables yet)
- etc.

The point is, you have to write data somewhere.  It doesn't *have to be* your main database tables.  But if different requests to a web application need to operate on the same persistent data then that data needs to be persistent somewhere.

Comment: Good explanation, like this one

Comment: I understand that, my problem is performance wise, I will take the approach of writing the data to a temporary database, I know this will be regarded as a new question, but do you know of any performance optimization techniques I can use in MVC with regards to saving large data to databases and reading and so on. Any specific one you've used and works well

Comment: @Papi: `"my problem is performance wise"` - That isn't at all what was asked in the question, though.  As for performance, the first step is always to measure before optimizing.  Otherwise you're not really optimizing, you're just guessing.  Modern databases tend to be pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate your Excel files:

1. Make a new class called `Validation`
2. Inside this class create a methode where you can validate your excel files.
3. Return true or false for valid or invalid.
4. For each excel file call this method and if it is valid, add it to a list with all your other valid excel files.
5. Save all valid excel files in your database

As far as I do not know your environment nor your validation criterias, it's hard for me to provide you any code. But maybe the list above can help you.